# How to run script after OpenVPN's TUN driver is up under Ubuntu

Tags: linux, openvpn

I would like to execute a bash script after a TUN driver (e.g. tun0) is up under ubuntu 9.04/9.10. I need it to use the assigned VPN IP in some configuration scripts.
Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance,

Humber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the manual page for the `--up cmd` configuration entry.  The script `cmd` is passed a whole lot of environment variables that tell it what is going on, and anything you might want to do is covered by those.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! That's exactly what I was looking for.
Sorry for not looking at the man page first.

In ubuntu 9.04, a init.d script named openvpn uses .conf files in /etc/openvpn to start a vpn process. I can edit edit that script and set OPTARGS with --up and --down directives.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `--up` switch (on command lien) or the `up` directive (in config file). See the [OpenVPN MAN](http://openvpn.net/man.html) page.